# Angular and GitHub API issues

Tags: angular, github-api

How can I list all the issues from GitHub? For example to list repositories I can use

```
https://api.github.com/users/MyUsername/repos
```

.

```
return this._http.get('https://api.github.com/users/' + this.username + '/repos?client_id=' + this.client_id + '&client_secret=' + this.client_secret)
.map(res => res.json());
```

How to do something similar with issues?

Comment: Can you post some additional information? Are you subscribing to your .get() observable? Is anything coming back? are there any errors?

Answer (score 0):

Use `https://api.github.com/repos/{username}/{reponame}/issues` to get repository issues

(this api does not return closed issues)